# Using not() in XPath

Tags: xpath

I would like how to use the "not" in XPath properly. I just can't seem to get it to work with attributes.

Say I have this expression: `//*[@name = 'Bob']` It is valid, and will return all nodes that have a name attribute equaling 'Bob'.

Now if I want all nodes that have a name attribute that do not equal 'Bob', I need to use an XPath such as: `//*[@name not(='Bob')]` but this is invalid.

I have tried multiple combinations with not() being placed in a different order, but I can't seem to get this to work. Could someone please inform me how to use not() properly?

Also, does the order change when using elements instead of attributes? Such as: `//name[text() = 'Bob']`

Thanks!  :)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

According to : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086.aspx, have you tried

```
//*[@name != 'Bob']
```

Comment: @mathieu: I would be better to quote the specs (not MS documentation), from http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#booleans *"If one object to be compared is a node-set and the other is a string, then the comparison will be true if and only if there is a node in the node-set such that the result of performing the comparison on the string-value of the node and the other string is true"*

Comment: @mathieu: This method works for numerical values but not for string values. //*[@numerical != 1] works. //*[@string != "someString"] does not. Only the root element is being returned!

Comment: @Alejandro: I did, but it only works for numerical values, not string values like I mentioned above. With the string value, the only result I get is the root node.

Comment: @iHeartGreek: This works. Other order comparison operators (like &gt;) only works for numbers (in XPath 2.0 you could use `op:gt` that works with collations).

Comment: @Alejandro: I don't know what the problem could be then.. it doesn't work in the implementation I have. What could be possible sources of the problem?

Comment: @iHeartGreek: Ask other question with input sample, desired output and in progress stylesheet, and someone could answer that to you. Meanwhile, you should mark this as answer, I think.

Comment: @Alejandro: ok, I selected it as the answer. I will try to ask another question next week.

Comment: @Alejandro: I think there is an issue with my XSL code, but it only became apparent to me once I used !=. I did some further testing, and found the searches do not go through entire hierarchy. I posted a question as I still can't fix it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3451325/xpath-results-from-xslt-are-incorrect-not-going-through-entire-xml

Answer (score 9):

Try

```
 //*[@name != 'Bob']
```

or

```
  //*[not(@name = 'Bob')]
```

should work both.

Comment: This method works for numerical values but not for string values. //*[@numerical != 1] works. //*[@string != "someString"] does not. Only the root element is being returned!

Comment: I am pretty sure that this will work for strings. Sure you did not make an error, for example, wrong case? The comparison is case-sensitive.

Comment: yes I tried various searches. I am only getting the root node returned. :S

Comment: Please post a complete example, a small XML file and the XPATH you are really trying, then we shall see further.

Comment: I think there is an issue with my XSL code, but it only became apparent to me once I used !=. I did some further testing, and found the searches do not go through entire hierarchy. I posted a new question as I still can't fix it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3451325/xpath-results-from-xslt-are-incorrect-not-going-through-entire-xml

Comment: Note that `//*[not(@name='Bob')]` will also match elements without a name attribute: since the `@name` node-set will be empty, `@name='Bob'` will be trivially false, and `not(@name='Bob')` will be trivially true.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion.  For some reason != wasn't working, but not() does.  I was trying to hide the header row in a table with a certain class.  The former returned no rows at all, the latter returned the non-header rows.

Answer (score 6):

```
//*[@name and @name != 'Bob']
```

Comment: Doesn't this give all elements whether they have @name or not? I need it to be an element with @name and then have it not equal 'Bob'

Comment: I think just //*[@name != 'Bob'] would work.. as others suggested.

BUT This method works for numerical values but not for string values. //*[@numerical != 1] works. //*[@string != "someString"] does not. Only the root element is being returned!

Comment: Sorry, it is my understanding that your solution does in fact work. I think there is an issue with my XSL code, but it only became apparent to me once I used !=. I did some further testing, and found the searches do not go through entire hierarchy. I posted a new question as I still can't fix it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3451325/xpath-results-from-xslt-are-incorrect-not-going-through-entire-xml